# RSpec objects being created but undefined method `each` for nilNilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following create method, which creates a new array of activities, loops the parameters of activities, set the `action_type` to the parameter `action_type`. Then create a new instance with the `action_type`. I then push the local variable activity into the `@activities` array and then create a new instance for comments and alert.

```
def create
  @activities = []
  params[:activities].each do |act|
    action_type = act[:action_type]
    activity = Activity.create(action_type: action_type)
    @activities << activity
    Comment.create(comment_text: act[:comment])
    Alert.create(alert_id: act[:alert_id])

  end
  render json: @activities
end
```

My problem occurs when I try to run the following RSpec test

```
 let(:valid_hash_attributes) do
    [
      {
        action_type:"Right-sized next generation application",
        entered_by:"Mrs. Cortney Goyette",
        alert_id:1,
        comment:"This is a acomment"
      }
    ]
   end

  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Activity" do
        expect {
          post :create, {:activities => valid_hash_attributes}, valid_session
        }.to change(Activity, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created activity as @activity" do
        post :create, {:activities => valid_hash_attributes}, valid_session
       assigns(:activity).should be_a(Activity)
        assigns(:activity).should be_persisted
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following output:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
>   ./app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:30:in`create'
>   ./spec/controllers/activities_controller_spec.rb:87:in `(root)'

What is really strange is that in the RSpec log it shows that these objects we're created as shown below:

> Parameters: {"activities"=>[{"action_type"=>"Right-sized next
>   generation application", "entered_by"=>"Mrs. Cortney Goyette",
>   "alert_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"This is a acomment"}]} Savepoint (0ms) 
>   SAVEPOINT active_record_1 SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "activities"
>   ("action_type", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES
>   ('Right-sized next generation application', '2013-10-18
>   13:17:46.129000', '2013-10-18 13:17:46.129000', 1) Savepoint (0ms) 
>   RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1 (0ms)  SELECT name FROM
>   sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = "comments" Savepoint
>   (0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1 SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "comments"
>   ("comment_text", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('This is a
>   acomment', '2013-10-18 13:17:46.212000', '2013-10-18 13:17:46.212000')
>   Savepoint (1.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1 (1.0ms)  SELECT
>   name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = "alerts"
>   Savepoint (0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1 SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO
>   "alerts" ("alert_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (1,
>   '2013-10-18 13:17:46.332000', '2013-10-18 13:17:46.332000') Savepoint
>   (0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1

Actually quite baffled in why this test is not passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second spec is passing `valid_attributes` to the controller, which is not defined (therefore nil). It should be `valid_hash_attributes`.

**edit**: according to the screenshot you posted on IRC (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7G2B.png), you're also using an incorrect hash key - your second test is passing in the `activity` param, not `activities`, therefore `params[:activities]` is nil.